# node.js sevver giving 504 when api taking longer than 1 mins

Tags: node.js, pm2

server.js

```
app.post("/api/media/image-upload", ImageUpload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    imageUrl: req.file.location,
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`Potential app listening on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

I use below command to deploy

```
pm2 start server.js
```

When i am uploading image it is big which is taking more than 1 minutes. But, i am getting 504 from server side.
How can i increase the timeout for pm2?

Comment: Sounds like your node app is behinad a other webserver/reverse proxy. You need to configure this webserver. Where is your app deployet/how does the setup/app stack looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pm2 start server.js --kill-timeout 3000`
this will lengthen the timeout to 3000ms

you can check other methods in  the [documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/signals-clean-restart/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20increase%20the%20PM2,%2Dtimeout%3DXXXX%20via%20CLI.)